# WCF/REST Logging

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, rest, logging

I was wondering if someone could show me how to log a simple request/response from my wcf rest service.

I am self hosting with a console application on the localmachine:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RawDataService), new Uri(baseAddress));
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            //binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IReceiveData), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I was really hoping all that would be required is something added to the hosting console app. I tryed following this but it was abit confusing http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

Just to note I am not using any app.config or web.config files.

EDIT:

I also cannot use any third party products for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about logging for debugging purposes or for monitoring in a live service?

If you are debugging you can just switch on WCF tracing. It will produce a very comprehensive log and there is a good free tool for viewing the log that comes as part of the Windows SDK - I presume when you say you can't use third party product it doesn't include built-in .Net and Windows SDK features...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle this is with Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) using the Castle Dynamic Proxy library. The idea is that you can decorate/proxy your service implementation with a dynamic class that intercepts every single method called on your service. No matter what method is called on your service, they'll be "intercepted" by your proxy and sent to a single method where you can log what you want and then you can finish the original call. Here's a quick sample of what that looks like:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    // No matter what service method is called, it's funneled through here.
    public void Intercept(IInvocation call)
    {
        MyLogger.Info("Starting call: " + call.Method.Name);

        // Actually invoke whatever method was originally called 
        call.Proceed();

        MyLogger.Info("Finished call: " + call.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

Now you need to create a proxy of your service class that uses this interceptor for all of its method calls. You can pretty up and abstract as necessary, but this is the basic jist:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
...

// Create your service object and then create a dynamic proxy of the object
// that will inject your logging interceptor logic.
ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
RawDataService service = new RawDataService();
RawDataService proxy = generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget<RawDataService>(
    service,
    new LoggingInterceptor());

// Register your proxy object, not the raw service w/ WCF
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(proxy, new Uri(baseAddress));
... rest of your code as it was ...
```

Now any call made to your RawDataService will go through the Intercept() method first and when it calls Proceed() your actual implemented service logic will happen. You can update the interceptor to handle exceptions, include a StopWatch and log parameters as needed but that's the basic idea.

My example shows you the brute force way of setting this up. The "cleaner" solution would be to use IoC to create your service instance/proxy but this should get your code doing what you want right now. For further reading, here's a link to the [Castle project's tutorial](http://stw.castleproject.org/%28X%281%29S%28351doi55hgkxcq55umr3ce45%29%29/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx) on using its AOP hooks:

Comment: In your logging interceptor class, be sure to include `using Castle.DynamicProxy` - keep in mind this is a 3rd partly library so if you don't have it you can get it from NuGet or download directly from [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html). You'll need to add references to your project for 'Castle.Core' and 'Castle.Windsor' too.

Comment: Ahh sorry Rob I cannot use any third party products. My mistake for not mentioning this in the question. Will update now.